# Interceptor breaks property injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

I use Ninject. The injected property of self-binded class is not resolved when the class has an interceptor. Up-to-date libraries are used:

```
  <package id="Castle.Core" version="3.2.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Ninject" version="3.2.0.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Ninject.Extensions.Interception" version="3.2.0.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Ninject.Extensions.Interception.DynamicProxy" version="3.2.0.0" targetFramework="net46" />
```

`Foo` class is self-binded:

```
public class Foo
{
    [Inject]
    public IBar Bar { get; set; }
}

public interface IBar
{
    void MyMethod();
}

public class Bar : IBar
{
    public void MyMethod() { }
}
```

The interceptor:

```
public class TestInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        invocation.Proceed();
    }
}
```

And two tests:

```
[Test]
public void Test1()
{
    var kernel = new StandardKernel();

    kernel.Bind<IBar>().To<Bar>();
    kernel.Bind<Foo>().ToSelf();

    var foo = kernel.Get<Foo>();

    Assert.IsNotNull(foo.Bar);
}

[Test]
public void Test2()
{
    var kernel = new StandardKernel();

    kernel.Bind<IBar>().To<Bar>();
    kernel.Bind<Foo>().ToSelf().Intercept().With<TestInterceptor>(); //the only diff

    var foo = kernel.Get<Foo>();

    Assert.IsNotNull(foo.Bar);
}
```

`Test1` is successful. `Test2` fails. Why? Is it expected behavior?

Comment: Try to make the `Bar` property `virtual`.

Comment: @YacoubMassad thanks, you found it! I'm sad to see such unclear behaviour in Ninject. Post your comment as answer if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would work if you make the `Bar` property `virtual` like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    [Inject]
    public virtual IBar Bar { get; set; }
}
```